# Joomla 4 Alias Menu loses original menu class

Tags: joomla-4.x, menu-item

In J4, I have a menu item (in main menu) loading a single article and I've added a unique class via the menu Page Display >> Page Class.
It has an alias of "commercial" and when used from the front end the URL is `/commercial`.

I have created another menu with a menu item that is an alias item pointing to the above menu item. The alias on this menu item is "commercial-info".

However, when visiting the link on the front-end, the page class is not used and the URL is `/?itemid=223` (the id number of the alias menu item (not the one it points to).

Also, the `<body>` gets a class added `no-layout no-task dir-ltr itemid-233` (as well as a number of other miscellaneous classes added).

(updated)

The custom module that is creating the links is building the links using this  code:

```
$menuItemURL = Route::_("index.php?Itemid={$menuItem->id}");
```

So the question is, how can I get the REAL URL using `Route::_` when the menu is an alias? (The above `Route::_` works fine for all other menu types other than alias).

Comment: I have come up with code to manually lookup the menu that the alias is pointing to and build the appropriate link/url; however, I'm wondering if there is any way to do that using just the Route:: function. I've not found any of help in the Joomla docs on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the menuitem params, as `'aliasoptions'`. This holds the itemid of the menuitem which the alias menuitem points to. So if you have your alias menuitem as `$menuItem` then do

```
$itemid = $menuItem->getParams()->get('aliasoptions');
$url = Route::_("index.php?Itemid={$itemid}");
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't in the joomla docs, I just found it by inspecting the menuitem object in a debugger. It should really be documented in the [Menu and Menuitems API Guide](https://docs.joomla.org/Menu_and_Menuitems_API_Guide) but the number of such param values that you'd need to list is rather offputting.